# Using generics with mapped conditional types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use generics with mapped types in order to map method types?

For example: can you create a mapped type in which you add a first argument of type `number` to every method?

Pseudo code (won't work)

```
interface Method<TS extends any[], R> { 
  (...args: TS): R;
}
interface NumberedMethod<TS extends any[], R> { 
  (n: number, ...args: TS): R;
}


type Numbered<T> = {
  // ERROR! Can't use generics here??
  <TS extends any[], R>[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends NumberedMethod<TS, R>? T[K]: T[K] extends Method<TS, R>: NumberedMethod<TS, R>: never;
};
```

Is there any way in which this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to extract the generic arguments `TS` and `R` from the method, you need to use the `infer` keyword before a type name in a conditional type (see [Type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496)). This should do what you want:

```
interface Method<TS extends any[], R> { 
  (...args: TS): R;
}
interface NumberedMethod<TS extends any[], R> { 
  (n: number, ...args: TS): R;
}


type Numbered<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Method<infer TS, infer R>? NumberedMethod<TS, R>: T[K];
};

type WithNumber = Numbered<{
    foo : number,
    bar(a: string): void
}> 
// same as 
// type WithNumber = {
//   foo: never;
//   bar: NumberedMethod<[string], void>; // This gets expanded by code completion when accessing the method usually 
// }
```

Comment: Wow. Conditional types just got a lot more powerful! Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @nicojs It was there from the beginning just it's a separate feature from vanilla conditional type, but yes `infer` is mind blowing :)

Comment: In your "same as" comment, did you mean `foo: number` instead of `foo: never`?  (Trying to make sure I understand your black belt type-jitsu is always a good exercise!)